# Superset cache warm-up doesn't work in kubernetes

Tags: apache-superset

I'm working with Superset deployed in a Kubernetes environment (Chart version 0.2.15, v3.1.0), and the Superset worker is unable to complete the cache process. The error it throws is as follows:

```
[2024-02-19 10:54:00,215: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] fetch_url[d2209a99-f8d3-442e-ab0e-2652b81a7e9e]: Error warming up cache!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/superset/tasks/cache.py", line 242, in fetch_url
    response = request.urlopen(  # pylint: disable=consider-using-with
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
celery_conf: |
    from celery.schedules import crontab
    class CeleryConfig:
      broker_url = f"redis://{env('REDIS_HOST')}:{env('REDIS_PORT')}/0"
      imports = (
          "superset.sql_lab",
          "superset.tasks.cache",
          "superset.tasks.scheduler",
      )
      result_backend = f"redis://{env('REDIS_HOST')}:{env('REDIS_PORT')}/0"
      task_annotations = {
          "sql_lab.get_sql_results": {
              "rate_limit": "100/s",
          },
      }
      beat_schedule = {
          "reports.scheduler": {
              "task": "reports.scheduler",
              "schedule": crontab(minute="*", hour="*"),
          },
          "reports.prune_log": {
              "task": "reports.prune_log",
              'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),
          },
          'cache-warmup-hourly': {
              "task": "cache-warmup",
              "schedule": crontab(minute="*/2", hour="*"), ## for testing
              "kwargs": {
                  "strategy_name": "dummy"
              },
          }
      }
    CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig
    THUMBNAIL_SELENIUM_USER = "admin"
```

Am I missing something? Is it a software error?